# opend ms word, past the data from access and save in vb6

Tags: vb6

I want to open new ms word file and copy the data from access (DAO connection)  and past the same in document and save in particular path when I click the command button. Please confirm if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Word object to do this. Please refer the code below.

```
Dim oWord As Object
Dim oDoc As Object
Set oWord = CreateObject("word.application")
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add
oWord.Selection.Paste
oWord.Visible = True
```

[Refer this link for more details](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/313193)